# C# simple game of life in WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, conways-game-of-life

I am creating a very simple version of the game of life.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life)

I am using a 30x80 array to track the cells as either alive or dead. Here is my code for the starting position of cells. I'm trying to render it in WPF

Here is my code for generating the initial position.

```
public void fixedArray()
{
    char characterForGame = getCharacterForGame();

    //char[,] gameArray = new char[30, 80];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 80; j++)
        {
            gameArray[i, j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    //Sets initial cells
    gameArray[1, 25] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[2, 23] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[2, 25] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[3, 13] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[3, 14] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[3, 21] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[3, 22] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[3, 35] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[3, 36] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[4, 12] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[4, 16] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[4, 21] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[4, 22] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[4, 35] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[4, 36] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[5, 1] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[5, 2] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[5, 11] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[5, 17] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[5, 21] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[5, 22] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[6, 1] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[6, 2] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[6, 11] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[6, 15] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[6, 17] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[6, 18] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[6, 23] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[6, 25] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[7, 11] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[7, 17] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[7, 25] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[8, 12] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[8, 16] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[9, 13] = characterForGame;
    gameArray[9, 14] = characterForGame;

    printArray();
}
```

my question is rather broad, but I can't find much when I google probably because of my poor terminology. How would I go about doing the animation so I can print this array each iteration? The text book I use shows an example with Timeline animations, but only the .xaml.

Comment: To be quite frank, your example is clearly for outputting to a console window (80 characters wide). So you need to clear up the question if you want to render something specifically in WPF or .Net GDI. At which point, your question is pretty much how do I do graphics in WPF...

Comment: @MeirionHughes sorry like I said my vocab is bad which is making it hard to find relevant answers. Yes the array I need to "animate" really just needs printed a set number of times to a text block.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question how to do it in **WPF**...

Add a window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" 
        Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyArray}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

add a new file:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public char[][] MyArray { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            MyArray = new char[30][];

            for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++)
            {
                MyArray[row] = new char[80];

                for (int col = 0; col < 80; col++)
                {
                    MyArray[row][col] = 'O';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should get you:

[image]

If you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern on the ViewModel, and use `ObservableCollection` instead of arrays (you can still nest them) then when you update the elements, the View will automatically change too.

You can then replace the `DataTemplate` for the character element to a graphic. Template Selectors might be useful here too.

Lots you could do, that I'll leave for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a simple game using c# then I suggest trying out [XNA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=23714) or [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/). You shouldn't worry about rendering, refreshing, etc. Look it up on the net, it's not as complex as you may think.

UPDATE:

Here you go assuming you have a WrapPanel named wp..

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel Name="wp">

        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int fixedHeight = 50;
            int fixedWidth = 50;
            char[,] gameArray = new char[30, 80];
            wp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            wp.MaxWidth = gameArray.GetLength(1) * fixedWidth;

            for (int i = 0; i < gameArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < gameArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    wp.Children.Add(
                        new System.Windows.Controls.Button
                        {
                            Content = string.Format("{0}-{1}", i, j),
                            Height = fixedHeight,
                            Width = fixedWidth,
                        }
                        );
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is for a class so I have to use WPF forms.

Comment: You should have mentioned that on your post. Anyway, both XNA and MonoGame supports XAML

Comment: My bad I'll edit that in, do you have any suggestions for simply printing an array a set number of time over a

Comment: Oops I implemented it on WinForms. Wait I'll convert it to WPF